# Heater pilot problem

Tags: thermocouple

My heater pilot light goes on and then off not sure why if does that, the gas goes on and then fan but only for seconds then off including the pilot.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Is this new behavior, and if so was anything else changed? What make/model is your heater, and what type of heater is it (gas furnace? gas boiler?)?

Comment: Is this natural gas or propane? Do other gas-fired appliances exhibit the same behavior?  Do you have good voltage at the thermocouple?